# Rank Of A matrix of system of homogeneous equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $C=A+\lambda B\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ of rank $r<n$, where $\lambda$ is real variable, so $C$ is a linear polynomial in $\lambda$ with matrix co-efficient.

so the collumns of $C$ are linearly dependent and hence there exists $x$ some non-zero collumn vector which satisfy the following equation
$$(A+\lambda B)x=0 \cdotp\cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cdotp(1)$$

suppose $x(\lambda)$ be a polynomial in $\lambda$ (with co-efficients are collumns) which is a solution of minimum degree $\epsilon$

i.e $x(\lambda)= x_0-\lambda x_1+\lambda^2x_3-\dots+(-1)^{\epsilon}\lambda^{\epsilon} x_{\epsilon}, x_{\epsilon}\ne 0$

now putting this solution in $(1)$ and then equating  powers of $\lambda$ we get a system of linear equation in the elements of the collumn $x_0,-x_1,\dots,(-1)^{\epsilon}x_{\epsilon}$

$$Ax_0=0$$ $$Bx_0-Ax_1=0$$ $$Bx_1-Ax_2=0$$ $$\dots\dots$$ $$Bx_{\epsilon-1}-Ax_{\epsilon}=0$$ $$Bx_{\epsilon}=0$$

now matrix of this system is $$M_{(\epsilon+2)\times (\epsilon+1)}= \begin{bmatrix}
 A&0&\dots\\ 
 B&A&\dots\\
 0&B&\dots\\
\dots&\dots&\dots\\
\dots&\dots&A\\
\dots&\dots&B\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is  how to show rank of $M_{(\epsilon+2)\times (\epsilon+1)}<(\epsilon+1)n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I have to claim in the beginning that I do not solve this problem by myself. I asked my classmate for help, who is a genius at algebra, and this answer is given by him.

Because $rank(M_{(\epsilon+2)\times (\epsilon+1)})\leq(\epsilon+1)rank\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\0\end{pmatrix}$. We will prove that $rank\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\0\end{pmatrix}<n$.

We denote $A=(\vec{a_1},...,\vec{a_n})$, $B=(\vec{b_1},...,\vec{b_n})$. $C(x)=A+xB$ can be seen as a matrix defined in the field $\mathbb{R}(x)$, i.e. $C(x)\in \mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}(x))$. Because for every x, we have $rank(A+xB)=r< n$. Thus, $det(A+xB)=0$, which means that the columns of A+xB are linearly dependent in the field $\mathbb{R}(x)$.

So, $\exists p_i(x), q_i(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$, s.t
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{p_i(x)}{q_i(x)}(\vec{a_i}+x\vec{b_i})=0$$
Then, $\exists r_i(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$, s.t
$$\sum_{i=1}^n r_i(x)(\vec{a_i}+x\vec{b_i})=0$$
Assume that the highest degree of $r_i(x)$ is k, and we can denote $r_i(x)$ as $\sum_{j=0}^kr_{ij}x^j$. Then we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^kr_{ij}x^j(\vec{a_i}+x\vec{b_i})=0$$
Compare the coefficients, and the equation above can be written in the form of matrix:
$$M_{(k+2)\times (k+1)}\begin{pmatrix}r_{10}\\r_{20}\\...\\r_{1k}\\...\\r_{nk}\end{pmatrix}=0$$
For $r_{10},r_{20},...,r_{1k},...,r_{nk}$ are not all zeros, we have the conclusion that 
$$rank(M_{(k+2)\times (k+1)})<(k+1)n$$

Thus, we have proved that
$$rank\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\0\end{pmatrix}<n$$

And the final conclusion can be reached.

Comment: Because every column of matrix M is of the similar form: $(0,...,0,A,B,...,0)^T$. Well, I think $\leq$ is more proper. I've edited it.

Comment: I've seen the book. For the $m\times n$ condition, the proof is similar. $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is the real-coefficient rational function field, and $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the real-coefficient polynomial ring. You can multiple $q_1(x)...q_n(x)$ on both sides of the equation, and then the coefficient of $(\vec{a_i}+x\vec{b_i})$ becomes a polynomial $r_i(x)$ instead of a rational fraction.

Comment: thank you, now why calculating the rank of the whole matrix  transformed into calculating the rank of a collumn which  ofcourse contains matrix $A,B$ and as you told similar to $(0,0,A,B,0,0\dots)^T$...?

Comment: as we know rank of a matrix is number of nonzero linearly indipendent collumn, I am getting confused here about the collumns as they itself consisted with matrices $A,B$, whose rank I don't know!

Comment: Uh, "column" is not "collumn"...If $rank(M)=(\epsilon+1)n$, then every block column $(0,...,A,B,...,0)^T$ must has rank n, otherwise "=" will not hold. And it's obvious that every such block column in the matrix has the same rank, i.e. if $rank(A,B,...,0)=a$, then $rank(0,A,B,...,0)=a$, and so on, this is an obvious fact. So if we can prove such a block column has a rank < n, the rank of the whole matrix will be $<(\epsilon+1)n$. And in the proof, we prove that for a certain k, "<" holds instead of "=", which means that for at least one block column, its rank < n.

Comment: what do you mean by highest degree of $r_i(x)$ is $k$? I see that $r_1(x)=p_1q_2\dots q_n,r_2(x)=p_2q_1\dots q_n,\dots,r_n(x)=p_nq_2\dots q_{n-1}$, now each $r_i$ has different degree, are you saying $r_k$ has highest degree $k$ for some $1<k<n$? and also why did you introduce a new variable $j$? I mean what is $r_{ij}$?

Comment: For the question about $k$, Yes. For the question about $j$, $r_i(x)$ (i=1,2,..,n) are polynomials, and I just assume that $r_i(x)=\sum_{j=1}^k r_{ij}x^j$, $r_{ij}$ is the real coefficient of the term $x^j$ in the polynomial $r_i(x)$.

Comment: what is $r_{10},r_{20},\dots$? if indexes are running from $1$, why $0$?

Comment: I'm sorry. "j" starts from 0. I've modified the answer.

Comment: why are you taking highest degree polynomial among $r_1,\dots r_n$? why not lowest degree? what is the reason of this appraoch? also clear me one thing that entries of $A,B$ are polynomials in $x$ right?or only real numbers?

Comment: If the degree of $r_i(x)$ is k'<k, I can also assume that $r_i(x)=\sum_{j=0}^kr_{ij}x^j$, in which $r_{i,(k'+1)},...,r_{i,k}=0$. Though they're zeros, I can still put the notation there. That's why I choose the highest, I don't think this is hard to understand. The entries of A,B are real numbers, but you can see them as polynomials with degree 0. The entries of C(x) are polynomials with degree 1.

Comment: Thanks! okay now $M_{{(k+2)}\times {(k+1)}}\times (r_{10},\dots,r_{nk})^T=0$ and not all $r_{10},\dots,r_{nk}$ are $0$ I understood, but these two statesment $\Rightarrow$ rank of $M_{{(k+2)}\times {(k+1)}}<(n+1)k$, how? and why?

Comment: If the rank=(k+1)n, the vector $(r_{10},\dots,r_{nk})^T$ will be a zero vector, according to the theory of homogeneous equation in linear algebra (if the coefficient matrix is of full rank, the solution of the homogeneous equation is a zero vector).